# Determine whether the function sequence $f_n(x)=b(x-n)$ converges pointwise or uniformly on given sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm supposed to determine whether the function sequence $f_n(x)=b(x-n)$ converges pointwise or uniformly on the following for $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$:

$
b(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1-x^2 & \text{if}\, x\in[-1,1]\\
 0 & \text{if}\, x\lt -1, \text{or } x\gt 1
\end{cases}
$

I'm not sure where to start. Am I trying to find if there's uniform convergence of $f_n(x)$ to $b(x)$ in those 2 piecewise cases? If $f_n(x)=1-(x-n)^2$, then that's a "shift" from $1-x^2$ so how would it converge ***at all*** to $b(x)$ then?

I was also given a couple propositions to help avoid having to prove these things from definition:

**Prop 14.6**: Let $f_n$ be pointwise convergent to $f$ on $D$. Then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $D$ to $f\iff \exists a_n\to 0, a_n\ge 0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le a_n$ $\forall x\in D$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough.

**Prop 14.7**: Assume $f_n$ be converges pointwise to $f$ on $D$. If there exists a sequence $x_n\in D$ such that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\ge C_n$ and $C_n\to C\gt 0$, then $f_n$ does not converge uniformly.

**Edit:** The intermediate questions are only helpful when find out if I'm correct about them. I think I have been ignoring the $0$ part of $b(x)$ by accident. $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=0$ since $x-n\lt -1$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: If $f_n$ converges, nothing says it converges "to $b(x)$".

Comment: Hint: $(f_n)$ does converge pointwise, to a very simple function.

Comment: @aschepler $1$? How do I know what point to look at?

Comment: Try plugging in a couple of points and seeing what happens when you take $n$ to be big. Extrapolate.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed points as in what? Points of $b(x)$? Points of $f_n(x)$?

Comment: Let $x = .5$. Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x).$ Try other $x$ values.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed that limit is $-\infty$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$, no?

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}$. What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ when $x$ stays the same?

Comment: @aschepler $-\infty$. I thought I said that to 1mdlrjcmed

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins That cannot be true, simply because $b$ takes only values in $[0,1]$, thus, also $f_n$ takes only values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I edited my post a few minutes after I replied to you with that since I forgot about $b(x)$ domain intervals. And actually, $b(x)$ takes any value and sends it to $0$ if it's not between $[-1,1]$, so the limit should be $0$, correct? And if so, that's my $f(x)$ for $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins Yes, that is the correct limiting function. Thus, if you want to check whether you have uniform convergence, you need to consider $$ \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \vert f_n(x) -f(x) \vert = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \vert f_n(x) \vert $$ and check whether this converges to $0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$. It helps to make a drawing of what $f_n$ looks like to get an intuition what the answer should be.